# Iterator no match operator= Error

Tags: c++, iterator

I have 2 classes namely classA and classB. Within classA there is a map dynamically declared on the heap memory.
In classB however, is trying to access classA map values using an iterator.
Unfortunately I have gotten the error no match operator= for the iterator.
If i were to move the map to classB, the iterator will work fine. Could someone assist me in this, it has been bothering me for awhile.
Thanks in advance.

```
class classA{
public:
  classA();
friend classB;
private:
  map <int,int>* _themap;
};

classA::classA(){
  _themap = new map<int,int>;
}

class classB{
private:
 classA* object = new classA();
 void accessthemap();
};

void classB::accessthemap(){

 map<int,int>::iterator it;
 it = object->_themap->begin();
 it = object->_themap->find();
}
```

Comment: Make it `object->_themap.begin()`. `_themap` is not a pointer.

Comment: @n.m. This should really be an answer, it would be nice to vote you up, and it would be good for superface to have an opportunity to accept the answer (and close the question).

Comment: First of all, how would this code compile? There are lot of mistakes like wrong class declaration etc

Comment: @cppcoder: Isn't that what he's asking?

Comment: @Tomalak He was concerned about iterator error. Whereas the class itself has error. I thought he might have overseen that.

Comment: @superface: You have a memory leak.

Comment: @cppcoder the code above is just a representation of my problem i face. I realize those syntax mistakes when i scribble the code here. I have make amendments on those syntactically incorrect area. The problem i'm facing is at the iterator

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
it = object->_themap.begin(); //not _themap->begin()
```

Because `_themap` is a non-pointer, so with it you've to use `.` operator, instead of `->` operator.

Beside, there are few more errors. If you've written `classA` as

```
//incorrect
classA{
   //...
};
```

which should be

```
//correct
class classA{
   //...
};
```

That is, you've to use the keyword `class` before the *class-name*. So define other classes such as `classB` using the keyword `class`.

Comment: assuming my syntaxes are all correct in this case. Do you see why the compiler still return Error when I'm trying to assign the iterator to the map of a different class.

Comment: @superface: The compiler still returns error because your assumption `assuming my syntaxes are all correct in this case` is incorrect.

Comment: To avoid further misunderstanding of the question. I've edited the syntax in the code block. The real problem is at it = object->_themap->begin(); it = object->_themap->find();

Answer (score 1):

You can't define members inside the class definition, so this is wrong:

```
classB{
private:
 classA* object = new classA();
 void accessthemap();
};
```

Instead just use a normal object (not to mention fix your other syntax errors):

```
class classB {
private:
 classA object;
 void accessthemap();
};
```

No need for dynamic allocation here.

Then write `object._themap.begin();`.